# How to trigger a CPU reset in Arduino?

Tags: arduino, esp8266, watchdog

I can't find any mention of a library function that will reset the Arduino and do a clean restart of my sketch. Is there a trick for doing this?

Also I tried to research the watchdog timer on the ESP8266 board but couldn't find coherent information on it. I would use this to do the reset if I could figure out how. (The [ESP8266 forum](https://www.esp8266.com/viewtopic.php?f=13&t=18610) has been no help.)

Comment: For what board?  That's a pretty important piece of info.  You mention an Arduino but then talk about an ESP8266.  Which one are you trying to reset?

Comment: I'm currently working with Adafruit's HUZZAH ESP8266 breakout board (https://www.adafruit.com/product/2471) but my question was meant to apply to Arduino generally and the ESP8266 more specifically. The ESP8266 SoC has an on-board CPU which is supported by the Arduino IDE. I have an application running well on it but would like to add the watchdog capability for more bulletproof operation.

Comment: I don't know about the ESP.  I do know that you're not going to get a general Arduino answer because it depends on which Arduino and which chip.  They're all different.  The AVR chips are easy to reset with the watchdog but I think the core for the ESP8266 is already using it.

Comment: I'm kind of surprised there isn't a library function call to reset.

Comment: You don't have to do anything to enable the watchdog timer on the ESP8266. It's just there as part of the underlying system. There are actually two timers - one in software, one in hardware. The software one can be controlled via the ESP class - google "esp8266 watchdog timer" and you'll find examples of how to do it. If you want to see the timer fire, just add a "while(1) ;" to your setup() or loop() and that will trigger the watchdog after a few seconds.

Comment: There are reset functions - ESP.reset() and ESP.restart(). Again, try googling. "ESP8266 arduino reset" and there first hit is about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are methods  `ESP.restart()` and `ESP.reset()` that might do what you want. They are both inside the ESP library, which is included in the ESP8266 Arduino Core.

https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/cores/esp8266/Esp.cpp

Comment: Thanks. Don't know how I missed it, but `ESP.restart()` is mentioned in the library docs (but not `ESP.reset()`): https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/latest/libraries.html. Would still like to find out about the watchdog timer, though.

Comment: add `while(1);` to some sketch open the Serial Monitor to bootlog baud rate and you will see "wdt reset" after a while